# Setup USB Audio Headset

Tags: 14.04, usb, sound, alsa

I can't seem to setup a USB audio device to play sound.  I do not have any speakers currently setup, so this is the only way I can play sound.  I'm currently trying to install a Dynex Cyber-acoustics AC-850 USB headset.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try "System Settings > Sound" from the sidebar, I do not see anything except "Built-in Audio", which does not work.

[image]

From the `lsusb` command, I am able to see my headset as `Bus 003 Device 002`:

```
jackq@HAL-9000:/etc/modprobe.d$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0461:4d81 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell N889 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0139 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Multimedia Headset [Gigaware by Ignition L.P.]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Likewise, I am able to see the device as a recognized sound card (device 1):

```
jackq@HAL-9000:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xfe500000 irq 48
1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - DYNEX USB Audio Device
                  C-Media Electronics Inc. DYNEX USB Audio Device at usb-000
```

I've tried following the steps from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices but that hasn't worked.  In fact, once I reboot alsa, device 1 disappears altogether from the `lsusb` list.

```
jackq@HAL-9000:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xfe500000 irq 48
```

In keeping with what the above link suggested, I commented out all the `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` lines in the "alsa-base.conf" file and added the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
## USB Magic, part 1
# from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices
alias snd-card-0 snd-usb-audio
alias snd-card-1 snd-hda-intel
# Make the Headset Logitech device appear as hw:0
options snd-usb-audio index=0
# To give the Logitech headset the device number hw:0, we enter the line
options snd-usb-audio index=0 vid=0x0d8c pid=0x0139
```

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: IIRC PulseAudio has problems when a device has an unusual number of channels. Try to upgrade PulseAudio.